# LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: 0x5586a71270c0: f32 = Constant<1036831949>

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I get the error `LLVM ERROR: Cannot select: 0x5644a6291a10: f32 = Constant<1036831949>` somewhere inside:

```
%a2 = load float, float* %a
%a3 = load float, float* %a
%cmp = fcmp one float %a3, 0.000000e+00
%not = xor i1 %cmp, true
%convert = zext i1 %not to i32
%conv = sitofp i32 %convert to float
%cmp2 = or float %conv, %a2
store float %cmp2, float* %a
```

Is there a possible type mismatch occurring here? I have encountered this error before, but in the context of a mismatch of types. Not sure what is wrong here, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue. `%cmp2 = or float %conv, %a2` is invalid because `or` only takes int types.

Tip to other newbies, try running `llc myfile.llvm` to find issues in your LLVM IR.